# Unable to insert new row to UITableView with dynamic number of Sections And Rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with dynamic number of sections and each section has dynamic number of rows.

My datasource array looks like this

```
var detailsList = [[Any]]()
```

However I do know the type which would be added to the list and they would be added in a particular order. Lets consider these types would be A, B, C.

Depending upon the availability of data from the API `detailsList` would be populated. Hence the array would look something like this:

```
[[A, A, A, A], [B, B, B], [C, C, C]]
```

In this example, the tableView has 3 sections and numberOfRows are dependent on the subarray count.

Here is how the dataSource looks like

```
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
            func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                return detailsList.count
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return detailsList[section].count
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
               if let _ = detailsList[indexPath.section] as? [A] {
                  return cellA
               } else if let _ = detailsList[indexPath.section] as? [B] {
                 return cellB
               } else if let _ = detailsList[indexPath.section] as? [C] {
                 return cellC
                } else if let _ = detailsList[indexPath.section] as? [D] {
                 return cellD
                }
 }
```

The problem which I am facing is when I want to insert a section.

Lets say DataSource before adding a array looks like this

```
detailsList = [[A, A, A, A], [B, B, B], [C, C, C]]
```

After adding a new section the dataSource looks like this

```
detailsList = [[A, A, A, A], [B, B, B], [C, C, C], [D, D, D, D]]
```

I am unable to say

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

App crashes with following exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table
>   view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the
>   number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

But if i say

`tableView.reloadData()` it works as expected.

is there another way to insert new section?

Comment: What is the indexPath when you call insertRows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you are trying to insert more rows, but what your array is telling you is that you need more sections. You should therefor use:

```
tableView.insertSections(sections: IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a section, so you need to use

```
let indexSet = IndexSet( integer:4)
tableView.insertSections( indexSet, with:.fade)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should call `insertRows` method inside 'beginUpdates' and 'endUpdates' method calls like so:

```
//update the array first
detailsList = [[A, A, A, A], [B, B, B], [C, C, C], [D, D, D, D]]

//call insert method inside begin and end updates
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

**UPD:** There is a special method `insertSections` when adding a section instead of a row.

Comment: That's not true, if you are doing just one operation of add/delete you don't have to call beginUpdates and endUpdates. You have to call them if you are doing multiple operation, so they are performed in batch.